# Text color gradient on the last line of an article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gradient

I have this code, which is an article with a toggle anchor "read more" and "read less", i want to add a gradiant color to the last line of the visible area of the article (before your press "read more" ).

This image may give you a clear idea :

[image]

There is the code:

```js
$('.wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.expand = !this.expand;
    $(this).text(this.expand?"Read less":"Read more");
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
});
```

```css
.small {
  height: 50px;
  width: 255px;
  overflow:hidden;        
}
.big {
  height: auto;
  width: 255px;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="small">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta aut dolores autem officia eveniet, earum, necessitatibus et, in ut dolorum optio id hic numquam repudiandae? Quos expedita aliquam nobis adipisci?.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Read more</a>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Tried using CSS pseudo classes?

Comment: Not yet, which pseudo classe is related to what am i asking for ?

Comment: You could add an `::after` pseudo class for the paragraph class `.small` and add an inner box-shadow to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account your example, this is my recommendation to solve your problem, there are several ways to do it, but an easy one without adding any additional HTML elements, would be to use the after pseudo selector

```js
$('.wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.expand = !this.expand;
    $(this).text(this.expand?"Read less":"Read more");
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
});
```

```css
.small {
    height: 50px;
    width: 255px;
    overflow:hidden;
    
}

.small:after {
    height: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50px - 0.5em);
    background: rgba(240,248,255,0) linear-gradient(to top,#fff,rgba(255,255,255,0)) repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: '';
}

.big {
    height: auto;
    width: 255px;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta aut dolores autem officia eveniet, earum, necessitatibus et, in ut dolorum optio id hic numquam repudiandae? Quos expedita aliquam nobis adipisci?.</p>
    </div> <a href="#">Read more</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, can you explain those two lines : top: calc(50px - 0.5em); and content ' '.

Comment: Of course! lets first tackle the easiest one, content: You cannot style generated content without defining what that content should be. If you don’t need any content, you can just set it to the empty string. Now the calc, as you may know, top is used to define the distance to the top on the selected element, so since your text element is 50px high, that is where the 50px came from, now, the 0.5em is a relative measure of the font size, meaning half of the font size, since the element is 1em high the calc css function, will subtract half of the font size to the total top.

Comment: I have limited amount of characters on the comments. Hope the explanation helps, and if so, remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and the explanation as well.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that effect with CSS only, making use of `pseudo` selectors and setting the background of the pseudo element. Something like the following will make that possible. You can play a bit with the positioning to your liking.

```css
.small p
{
    position: relative;
}

.small p:after
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(240,248,255,0) linear-gradient(to top,#fff,rgba(255,255,255,0)) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="small">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta aut dolores autem officia eveniet, earum, necessitatibus et, in ut dolorum optio id hic numquam repudiandae? Quos expedita aliquam nobis adipisci?.</p>
    </div> <a href="#">Read more</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `linear-gradient`

```js
$('.wrapper').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.expand = !this.expand;
$(this).text(this.expand?"Read less":"Read more");
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.small, .big').toggleClass('small big');
});
```

```css
.small {
height: 50px;
width: 255px;
overflow:hidden;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000, #fff);
color:transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.big {
height: auto;
width: 255px;
}
```

```html
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="small">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta aut dolores autem officia eveniet, earum, necessitatibus et, in ut dolorum optio id hic numquam repudiandae? Quos expedita aliquam nobis adipisci?.</p>
</div> <a href="#">Read more</a>

</div>
```